# Jump to next code cell (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to move the focus to the next cell of my Jupyter notebook. I've written a Javascript function that is fired when a user presses an HTML button. I added this button to my notebook by making use of functionality from IPython.core.display.HTML. This is the HTML part for the button:                          button onclick="set_params();" [in html brackets]. In the function - yes, with name set_params - I prepare a command that should be executed by the Python kernel. I establish that this is actually done when the button is pressed. Afterwards I want the cursor to move to the next cell - and that is not happening unfortunately. Here is part of my Javascript function:

```
var command = 'input_params = [' + names + ']';
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(command);
i = IPython.notebook.get_selected_index();
IPython.notebook.select(i+1);
```

I even checked with some extra code whether the cell with index i+1 is really a cell and it is. Why is the focus not moving?

Answer (score 0):

If you import Javascript:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
```

You can do something like:

```
def goto_cell_two():
    display(Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([2])"))

go_to_cell_two()
```

Cells start with index 0

Comment: Thanks for thinking along with me. I'm afraid I've not been clear enough. First a question: what's the difference beween IPython.notebook and Jupyter.notebook? Anyway, I want to invoke IPython.notebook from within a Javascript function which is triggered by pressing a button. Both the Javascript and the button are embedded in an html block. And that block is inserted by means of IPython.core.display. And then, I don't want to execute the next cell. I just want it to get the focus. I've tried by getting a handle to the code_mirror of that cell and by invoking it's focus method, but to no avail.

Comment: With the following 3 lines added to the code above, the focus is actually set to the next cell. This can be seen when debugging the Javascript in the browser. After the Javascript is executed however, the focus is shifted back to the previous cell with the button. The question is therefore: how can that behaviour be changed?

    cell = IPython.notebook.get_selected_cell();
    cm = cell.code_mirror;
    cm.focus();

Comment: @Dobedani Did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar problem with the input() function. In order to respond to input(), the user has to click in the same cell. This transfers the focus back to this cell, away from the next cell.

Comment: Hello @DavidEpstein, to be honest I did not. However, I learnt that there is a Python package called ipywidgets that can help us when a notebook needs to have user-friendly features like the one described above. Read the docs here: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Comment: @Dobedani I went to the link and searched for "focus" and "next cell". Neither were helpful, so my guess is that ipywidgets would not help.

Answer (score 0):

A few million years later ....

I end up calling 3 javascript functions consequently, namely `select_next()`, `focus_cell()`, and `execute_selected_cells()`. All these calls can be combined in one procedure in the first cell, and then call this function every time you want to jump into the next cell.

```py
def run_next(ev):
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.select_next()'))
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.focus_cell()'))
    display(Javascript('IPython.notebook.execute_selected_cells()'))
```

So in the "linear" part of a code without any input from the user, this function is called at the end of each cell

```py
run_next(None)
```

However, in interface cells, this function should be called only when the user selects/accepts parameters and these parameters are correct.

```py
recacceptbtn = widgets.Button(
    description='Accept',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='success', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click to accept',
    icon='check-square'
)
def rec_check_update_runnext(evn):
    # testing parameters
    if recfile.value is not None and recprobe.value is not None:
        # saving parameters
        run_next(evn)
    else:
        display(Markdown('**You must select file and probe!**'))
    
recacceptbtn.on_click(rec_check_update_runnext)
```

I haven't tested this approach extensively, but it works so far and works pretty well.